# how to find all the strings that ended with xml with regex

Tags: regex

How can I find all the strings which is ended with .xml
I try with new `RegExp("^\.xml")` which is not working any idea?

Comment: Probably you need `\.xml$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` means at the start of the string. `$` is the opposite of it. You would need

```
var rgx = /\.xml$/gm
```

Note that I've included `m` flag, since I think that text might span many lines. If that's not the case, remove the `m` from the regex.

Comment: I try it and its not working

Comment: @AlBundy what's the tool or language you're using for it?

Comment: I dont use tool i try it in my program for string like /reso/~20128~/view/ail.view.xml  and its not working...

Comment: @AlBundy: This should work. How are you using it? Edit your question and add piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

It depends in which format you have your files (if each file name on a separate line or it's just a text and so on).

Assume that file name consist of letters, dots and dash signs I would try this pattern: `[A_Za-z\-\.]+\.xml`

Or if you want to find only file names, without extension, use this one: `[A_Za-z\-\.]+(?=.xml)`